# How can I restore my Stored Procedures again into dababase at once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I had done `generate script` and take out my 100+ `stored procedures` into a separate 100 files like we take backup now i made changes into those files.
but now i need to `alter` all those `original stored procedures`
from database.
i mean to say now all those 100 files i need to again load into database.

How can I do this like I had `generate script` to take out those sp's from database
is there any way to `restore all new sp's` into same database at once?

please help.

Comment: Have you already changed your 100+ stored procedures in the database? Or have you changed them in some text file and yet to commit them to the database? Your post is confusing a bit.

Comment: i take out from database as a file and changed it into file now i need to restore those changed sp into database

Comment: Yes, please clarify a bit what you are trying to do. You want to update the saved files with the changes from the database while keeping the changes you made manually? Then you should use a version control system or a diff tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to take out the scripts of stored procedures, you can take out them using "Generate Script" you shall get CREATE scripts. Once you change the scripts' body, you can rerun the scripts on the DB. But before that you can either drop the SP in the database or change the CREATE statement to ALTER in the script file.

One more way is to generate ALTER script when you take out the script. But this works with one proc at a time. You can right-click the SP and select "Script Stored Procedure as -> ALTER to -> File..." from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup your database stored procedures into a file, and restore them to your new database server using Backup and Restore tool.

Answer (score 0):

[ApexSQL Build](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_build.aspx) does exactly what you need. It executes SQL scripts against new or existing databases, and you can specify to drop the object first, so there will be no conflicts when executing `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements 
You can create T-SQL, C# or exe

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use this script for execute in your database...

```
Select 
    Convert(varchar(Max), Substring([RowLog Contents 0], 33, LEN([RowLog Contents 0]))) as [Script] 
from 
    fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)
```

You will see script stored procedure are dropped.

Good luck :)